# Different number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have an old database in Sql Server 2000 which I still have to maintain.
I have these two queries:

```
SELECT col1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   someTable
WHERE  YEAR = 2012
       AND c_id = 1
       AND p_id = 4
GROUP BY
       col1


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   someTable
WHERE  YEAR = 2012
       AND c_id = 1
       AND p_id = 4
       AND col1 = '11111'
```

When I find this same value '11111' in first query it shows 3 more rows then in second query. How is this possible? There is only problem for this value of kol1.
It also produces different sum.

Is there any chance that database corruption or something like that could produce this problem?

I tried this update:

```
update sometable
set col1=ltrim(rtrim(col1))
where c_id=1
and p_id=4
and year=2012
```

It has thrown this error:

Could not find the index entry for RID '16140001100032303132811300400' in index page (1:76450), index ID 2, database 'xxx'.

Comment: can you provide queries output ? it's not entirely clear what you're asking. second query will always produce single row. `count(*)` in first query returns 3 for row with `col1='11111'` and `count(*)` in second query gives different number ?

Comment: Output looks like this:
00001 | 25
00002 | 11
...
11111 | 530

And for second query result is 527

Comment: @user1659786 Corruption is not really likely, there will be some anomoly with the data tself

Comment: What are the datatypes of all columns ? Perhaps just post entire DDL for the table.

Comment: col1 is varchar(20), others are of no importance.

Comment: so corrupt index possibly ? try to rebuild indexes ?

Comment: After few tries I managed to rebuild indexes.
Now it produces correct results in both cases.
Thanks everybody for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody for trying to help me.
After unsuccessfully trying to update row I did index rebuild, updated col1 with ltrim(rtrim()) and now it produces correct results.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your table has 4 rows with the same value for corresponding fields. I assume something like

```
col1 | year | c_id | p_id | any_field
11111| 2012 | 1    | 4    | value_1
11111| 2012 | 1    | 4    | value_2
11111| 2012 | 1    | 4    | value_3
11111| 2012 | 1    | 4    | value_4
```

But, any_field is not selected and you will see only one record grouping by col1 because of the other duplicated fields.

Comment: No, count(*) must display 1 without "any_field" in the SELECT clause. Your grouped query must be shorter than the other one. Isn't it?

Comment: Count(*) should display 4 for col1 with value '11111'.
It displays one row, but value of count(*) is 4.

Comment: Sorry, you're right. Is this the case? 1 row and count(*) = 4 or similar result depending on your table rows...?

Comment: Something like that. When grouped it shows 530 for col1='11111'. 
When filtered by col1='11111' it shows 527.

Comment: whoops, I'm expecting the inverse result. Try this:

`SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   someTable
WHERE  YEAR = 2012
       AND c_id = 1
       AND p_id = 4
       AND col1 LIKE '11111%'`

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance, you are grouping by col1, in the second you are specifying an exact value to filter by. It is possible that you have trailing spaces after some of the values in col1. For example...

```
'11111'
'11111 '
'11111  '
```

...will give you 3 rows in a GROUP BY but only the first will return results in your second query. Try using the RTRIM() function

```
SELECT RTRIM(col1) AS col1,
       COUNT(*)
FROM   someTable
WHERE  YEAR = 2012
       AND c_id = 1
       AND p_id = 4
GROUP BY
       RTRIM(col1)


SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   someTable
WHERE  YEAR = 2012
       AND c_id = 1
       AND p_id = 4
       AND RTRIM(col1) = '11111'
```

Comment: Even when grouping with ltrim(rtrim(col1)) there is different result.

Comment: How many rows returned when you remove the COUNT() from the second query?

Comment: @user1659786 Have you simplified your example for us? Are you actually joining onto another table at all?

Comment: No, no joins. I only renamed table and column name, as you can see.